# button tooltip extjs

Tags: button, extjs, tooltip, extjs3

I have added a button to a tab panel in the center region by calling

```
var add = tabSelection.addButton({
  id            : 'add',
  text          : 'Add',
  hidden        : true,
  tooltip       : 'Please highlight the correct value and click Add to create new contact',
  handler       : addContact
});
```

There are two radio buttons in the west region in an accordion layout, labeled 'internal' and 'external'. I want the tool tip to be changed dynamically by capturing the radio button click.

I am able to capture the radio button click and when I set the tooltip of the button accordingly, 
`add.setToolTip('Please highlight the correct value and click Add to create new internalcontact');` if internal client is clicked.
`add.setToolTip('Please highlight the correct value and click Add to create new external contact');` when external is clicked.

Comment: Could you reword this or provide more information? It is difficult to determine whether you are even asking a question here.

Answer (score 8):

You need to initialise tooltips for it to work:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

And use qtip instead of tooltip.

Comment: If you're using QuickTips all over an application, what file would you put this in?

Comment: Why `Ext.QuickTips.init();` and not `Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();`?

Comment: The answer was posted over 5 years ago for ExtJS3, the latest version is ExtJS6. I don't use ExtJS anymore.

Comment: Please tell my employer that.

Answer (score 3):

Also worked for me (on ExtJS 4.1):

```
Ext.getCmp('buttonId').setTooltip('Tooltip you want to insert');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without using id, for e.g. with a button tooltip:

```
 var prev_button = new Ext.button.Button({
            cls: 'prevButton',
            listeners: {
                mouseover: function(btn) {
                    btn.setTooltip('1 ' + granularity.getValue()
                                   + ' ' + _('before'));
                }
            }
        });
```